# IndentationError: unexpected unindent in time series

Tags: time, series

The code i wrote in time series forecasting is as follows.
It keeps getting the error.

```
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(indexedDataset,order=param,seasonal_order=param_seasonal,enforce_stationarity=False,enforce_invertibility=False)
            results = mod.fit()
            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param,param_seasonal,results.aic))
except: continue
```

---

```
File "<ipython-input-211-c755485ed830>", line 7
    except: continue
                     ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(indexedDataset,order=param,seasonal_order=param_seasonal,enforce_stationarity=False,enforce_invertibility=False)
            results = mod.fit()
            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param,param_seasonal,results.aic))
        except: 
            continue
```

`except` needs to be at the same level of indent with `try`.
Please be more careful with indentation when you write python scripts.